# Building Pybind11 with setuptools for NEON intrinsics

Tags: python, setuptools, pybind11, neon

I am trying to compile/bind a python extension written in C++ that uses NEON intrinsics using
setuptools build of PyBind11. But it keep giving me errors.

(arm_neon.h:28:2: error: "NEON intrinsics not available with the soft-float ABI. Please use -mfloat-abi=softfp or -mfloat-abi=hard"
#error "NEON intrinsics not available with the soft-float ABI. Please use -mfloat-abi=softfp or -mfloat-abi=hard")

To reproduce:
clone https://github.com/pybind/python_example
Add #include <arm_neon.h> to the main.cpp

Then I tried to install/build it using pip, this gives me the following error:

arm_neon.h:28:2: error: "NEON intrinsics not available with the soft-float ABI. Please use -mfloat-abi=softfp or -mfloat-abi=hard"
#error "NEON intrinsics not available with the soft-float ABI. Please use -mfloat-abi=softfp or -mfloat-abi=hard"

So, I tried to add these options to the compiler flags by defining:
extra_compile_args=["-mfloat-abi=hard", "-O3", "-mcpu=native"]

But It still fails, and I see from the output:
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfloat-abi=hard' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]

However there are some gcc parts in the output as well, so I tried to force the clang++ compiler by
setting:
os.environ["CC"] = "clang++"
In the top of setup.py

However I still get the same error.
(I have also tried a bunch of other tricks, but I feel that im just searching in the wrong direction so I will not list these).

I can compile an stand alone c++ file with clang so it seems like im doing something wrong with the setuptools configurations.

I am running a Macbook Pro M2.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. Turns out the default anaconda uses x86_64 and Rosetta instead of native ARM.
So you have to download the miniconda that supports ARM to make this work!